# Microsoft Visio Professional 2016 - Changing the connector handle points color and size

Tags: connector, microsoft-visio-2016, handle

Is there a way to change the connector's handle point properties - size, color? It is very difficult to see (at least for me) the small blue dot on the black line.

Thanks,

Sovy